# Compare each and every cell in a colum by custom macro (unhandy for loop)

Tags: excel, vba

i'm currently trying to compare each and every cell in a column with each other in order to find duplicates. I wrote below code, i know it as possible via default Excel functions, but i would like to write a macro with the above mentioned function. Excel currently doesn't respond when i run my code, my guess is that i run a double for loop with 14K cells to compare is each resulting in 14.000*14.000 loops, which is kinda unhandy. Any help will be appreciated :).

```
Sub findidentical()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ColumnG As Integer

x = 0
ColumnG = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("G:G"))
'ColumnG is 14K cells long'
For i = 2 To ColumnG
    For j = 1 + 1 To ColumnG
        If Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(j, 7).Value Then
            x = x + 1 & Cells(i, 7).Font.Bold = True & Cells(j, 7).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Range("L25").Text = "Amount of duplicates"
Range("L26").Value = x

End Sub
```

Comment: why not use built Excel functions inside the vba. Specifically. Advanced Filter > Copy Unique Values for Column G, then count the unique values. Why make life harder when you don't have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub findidentical()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ColumnG As Integer

x = 0
ColumnG = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("G:G"))
'ColumnG is 14K cells long'
For i = 2 To ColumnG
    For j = i + 1 To ColumnG
        If Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(j, 7).Value Then
            x = x + 1
            Cells(i, 7).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(j, 7).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Range("L25").Text = "Amount of duplicates"
Range("L26").Value = x

End Sub
```

First you need to make each command in the if statement its own line or separate them with `:` instead of `&`.  `&` is a string concatenation not a command separator.

Second there is no reason to start Loop j at 2 it has already been compared to everything above.  So start it at `i+1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes minor typo with 1+1, i actually meant i+1 :).